# Selecting a specific table cell using CSS

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I scraped the rankings table from [atpworldtour.com](http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/rankings/single) and I'm trying to access the player names.

An example of a row in the table looks like this:

```
<tr>
  <td class="rank-cell">1</td>
  <td class="move-cell">
    <div class="move-none"></div>
    <div class="move-text">
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="country-cell">
    <div class="country-inner">
      <div class="country-item">
        <img src="/~/media/images/flags/srb.png" alt="SRB" onerror="this.remove()">
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="player-cell">
    <a href="/en/players/novak-djokovic/d643/overview" data-ga-label="Novak Djokovic">Novak Djokovic</a>
  </td>
  <td class="age-cell">28</td>
  <td class="points-cell">
    <a href="/en/players/novak-djokovic/d643/rankings-breakdown?team=singles" data-ga-label="rankings-breakdown">15,785</a>
  </td>
  <td class="tourn-cell">
    <a href="/en/players/novak-djokovic/d643/player-activity?matchType=singles" data-ga-label="player-activity">17</a>
  </td>
  <td class="pts-cell">1,500</td>
  <td class="next-cell">0</td>
</tr>
```

I tried a few different ways of pulling this information. So far the most success I've had so far is with this:

```
url = "http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/rankings/singles"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

doc.css("tr").each do |row|
  puts row.css("td a")
end
```

The problem is, there are two other links in each row after the player's name so I get them all lumped together. Player's names are the fourth cell in the table so I tried to pull the fourth cell first and then access the link:

```
doc.css("tr").each do |row|
  cell = row.css("td")[3]
  puts cell.css("a").text
end
```

but that returns the error `undefined method 'css' for nil:NilClass`.

Upon further investigation, `cell` seemed to be storing ALL the cells with the player names instead of just the one for the current iteration of `row`, but when I then tried to iterate through `cell` I got the same `undefined method` error.

I also tried to solve this problem using XPath:

```
doc.xpath("//tr").each do |row|
  puts row.xpath("/td[3]/a").text
end
```

but the output is a big area of blank space where the names should be listed.

1. Are there any tips about what I'm doing wrong?
2. Can anyone point me toward detailed documentation for using CSS/XPath selectors with Nokogiri I'd be grateful.

Everything I've found so far only covers the very basics and I'm having trouble finding information on how to perform more complex operations.

---

I actually got it working using:

```
doc.xpath("//tr").each do |row|
  puts row.at_css("a").text
end
```

but any help finding proper documentation/tutorials for using XPath and CSS selectors with Nokogiri would still be great.

Comment: What about `doc.css('.player-cell a').map(&:text)`?

Comment: Yes, that works as well and is much nicer, thank you. If you could put it in an answer along with an explanation I'd be glad to accept it :)

Comment: Questions asking us for tutorials links are off-topic. It's part of your research for an answer. Stack Overflow is FULL of answers showing and using CSS/XPath with Nokogiri so search here and read the Nokogiri Node documents. Complex searches are built using simple searches; complex selectors mask problems so start with small searches and slowly aggregate and test to see if you can still reach what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help shed some light on what's happening:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<table><tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr></table>')
```

`at` returns the first matching Node. In this case it's the `<tr>`. Using `text` returns all the text inside it concatenated together:

```
doc.at('tr').to_html # => "<tr>\n<td>foo</td>\n<td>bar</td>\n</tr>"
doc.at('tr').text # => "foobar"
```

Using `search` returns a NodeSet, which is most easily thought of as an Array. In this case it'll return two elements, one for each `<tr><td>` pair:

```
doc.search('tr td').size # => 2
```

`text` will return the text for all Nodes in the NodeSet, concatenating the strings again:

```
doc.search('tr td').to_html # => "<td>foo</td>\n<td>bar</td>"
doc.search('tr td').text # => "foobar"
```

However, by iterating over each Node in the NodeSet we *can* see the individual text:

```
doc.search('tr td').map(&:text) # => ["foo", "bar"]
```

An alternate, but slightly slower, way to do the same thing is to find the `<tr>` Node first, then searching inside it for the individual `<td>` nodes:

```
doc.at('tr').search('td').size # => 2
doc.at('tr').search('td').to_html # => "<td>foo</td>\n<td>bar</td>"
doc.at('tr').search('td').text # => "foobar"
```

Again, using `map` we can iterate over them and get the text without concatenation:

```
doc.at('tr').search('td').map(&:text) # => ["foo", "bar"]
```

Here's the difference in speed using a single vs. separate selectors to descend and select the `<td>` nodes:

```
require 'fruity'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<table><tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr></table>')

compare do
  single_selector { doc.search('tr td').map(&:text) }
  separate_selectors { doc.at('tr').search('td').map(&:text) }
end
# >> Running each test 32 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> single_selector is faster than separate_selectors by 2x ± 0.1
```

The difference is due to a single round-trip call to libXML2 for `tr td` vs. two for `doc.at('tr').search('td')`.

Unfortunately, *sometimes* we're forced into using the longer, slower form, if we need to use conditional logic or access multiple disparate types of child nodes in the order they're presented in the markup.

Answer (score 0):

The table cell containing the player's name has a class `player-cell`:

```
<td class="player-cell">
  <a href="/en/players/novak-djokovic/d643/overview" data-ga-label="Novak Djokovic">Novak Djokovic</a>
</td>
```

You can use this class to fetch the elements:

```
doc.css('.player-cell a').map(&:text)
#=> ["Novak Djokovic", "Roger Federer", "Andy Murray", ...]
```

Even without an explicit class, you could fetch the 4th column via:

```
doc.css('td:nth-child(4) a').map(&:text)
#=> ["Novak Djokovic", "Roger Federer", "Andy Murray", ...]
```

Or using XPath:

```
doc.xpath('//td[4]/a').map(&:text)
#=> ["Novak Djokovic", "Roger Federer", "Andy Murray", ...]
```